# Segmentation Fault on malloc()

Tags: c

im having a problem in my code, when i run it i got a segmentation fault in malloc() function. here's my code, im new here so sorry if i write something wrong.

Sorry my bad english !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef char String[50];
bool equalsIgnoreCase(char*,char*);

void main(){

 String nome;
 printf("Digite um nome: "); //name
 scanf("%s",nome);
  if(equalsIgnoreCase(nome,"TESTE")){ //test
     printf("Strings iguais."); 
  }else printf("Strings diferentes.");
}


bool equalsIgnoreCase(char *str1 , char *str2){
   char *a,*b;
   a = malloc(sizeof(char)); //segmentation fault here
   b = malloc(sizeof(char));
   for(;str1 != '\0';str1++,str2++){
     a = tolower(str1);
     b = tolower(str2);
     if(strcmp(a,b)!=0){
            free(a);
            free(b);
        return false;
    }
}
  free(a);
  free(b);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you get it the *first time* `malloc` is called?

Comment: Do you understand that `a = malloc(sizeof(char))` is allocating 1 byte of memory?  You cannot use that to store a string (the terminating null byte will consume the one byte that's available).  If you only want one byte, just declare it.  You are also mixing up pointers vs. what they point to rather severely.

Comment: `a = tolower(str1);..if(strcmp(a,b)!=0){` is wrong.

Comment: ohh i got it now, thanks !! :p

Comment: Are you sure you got a segmentation fault in `malloc()` function? Did you use a debugger?

Comment: yea, it stops debugging in `a = malloc(sizeof(char))` line

Comment: There are so many things wrong on this code I don't know where to start.

Comment: A bug not mentioned yet is that `scanf("%s"` should be `scanf("%49s"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `malloc()` and `free()` in this case. They are causing memory leak.

Also note that what is returned from `tolower()` is a character, not a pointer. Converting it to a pointer has little chance to yield a valid pointer.

Casting what is passed to `tolower()` from `char` to `unsigned char` is good because `char` may be signed and passing not in the range of `unsigned char` nor `EOF` to `tolower()` invokes *undefined behavior*.

Another point is that `str1 != '\0'` is not a correct way to tell if `str1` is pointing at the end of string, and that you should also check for `str2`.

Finally, you should use `const char*` for strings that are not to be modified.

Your code should be like this:

```
bool equalsIgnoreCase(const char *str1 , const char *str2){
  for(;*str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0';str1++,str2++){
    if(tolower((unsigned char)*str1) != tolower((unsigned char)*str2)){
       return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Or using `a` and `b`, like this:

```
bool equalsIgnoreCase(const char *str1 , const char *str2){
  int a, b;
  for(;*str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0';str1++,str2++){
    a = tolower((unsigned char)*str1);
    b = tolower((unsigned char)*str2);
    if(a != b){
       return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Also don't forget to

- change the prototype declaration of `equalsIgnoreCase` to `bool equalsIgnoreCase(const char*,const char*);` to match the new function.
- add `#include <ctype.h>` to use `tolower()`.
- change the return type of `main()` to `int` to match the standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it made my code more simple and easy to understand, but i have a question: when i know if `malloc()` will cause memory leak ?

Comment: When pointers to allocated buffer are gone before the buffer are freed.

Comment: Your `equalsIgnoreCase` return true if try equalsIgnoreCase("TEST", "TESTed")

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty wrong on this code.

Let me start by saying that C already has a function to compare strings ignoring case-sensitivity, its called `stricmp()`, and works very much like `strcmp()` except it ignores case, you don't have to write your own.

Another important thing to point out is that `a`, `b`, `str1` and `str2` are all **pointers**.

When you do `a = tolower(str1)` you are not doing anything meaningful because `str1` is not a character, its a pointer, and you are also losing the reference to the memory you have just allocated, and trying to `free()` memory in the stack which is invalid. One correct way of doing it, would be `*a = tolower(*str1)`.

Also, the only string that fits in 1 `char` length is an empty one. Strings in C are null-terminated, which means you need 2 `char` to make a string with 1 character, because it has to be followed by `\0` to be a valid C string.

Using `malloc()` here is also pointless, as pointed out on the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36994820/156811).

Answer (score 0):

There has **two bug** in your code which may cause segmentation fault.

1. `for(;str1 != '\0';str1++,str2++){`

compare str2 and '\0', or it will run out of str2.

2. `if(strcmp(a,b)!=0){`

strcmp need char* and two bytes in this case, but a and b only has sizeof(char) which only one byte.

simple compare by `*a != *b`

at last, i fix the segmentation fault but the **equalsIgnoreCase** remain **logical error**, finish it by yourself.
`

```
bool equalsIgnoreCase(char *str1 , char *str2){
   char *a,*b;
   a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); //segmentation fault here
   b = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
   //for(;str1 != '\0';str1++,str2++){
   for(;*str1 != '\0' && *str2 != '\0';str1++,str2++){
     *a = (char)tolower((int)*str1);
     *b = (char)tolower((int)*str2);
     //if(strcmp(a,b)!=0){
     if (*a != *b) {
            free(a);
            free(b);
        return false;
    }
}
  free(a);
  free(b);
  return true;
}`
```

Comment: 1. `str1 != '\0'` and `str2 != '\0'` won't be true before going out-of-range. Compare with what is pointed by them, not the pointers itself. 2. They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: thank u for your advise. for 1, i had corrected it. for 2, cast malloc() to make compile success (VS2010 need cast)

Comment: I got the error, if any string is **larger** than another will return true, i fix that, thanks for the help.